# Download form plugin for Wordpress

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I would like to create a form with name and email field. Users click submit and it will let them to download a file. Any plugin in Wordpress so that:
1. Users don't have to sign up as Wordpress member. Just simple fields (name, email)
2. Either the file being transfered right away to the users or download link is dynamic. This to prevent people to copy link to send to someone else.

Any thought?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a thought: Create a form with name and email field. Users click submit and it will let them download a file. If you want to code it (which is simple) give it a try. If you encounter a specific problem, ask for a solution here. If you want a form plugin, google it or ask at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What is the best and easy to use form plugin for Wordpress?

Comment: Is there a way to generate dynamic download URL? So that after the form filled out, people cannot copy that link to send to someone else to download without filling out the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: FormBuilder and Download Manager. Done! Thanks.